# Returning both data and an error in a resolver

Tags: graphql

In [issue 591](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/591#issuecomment-262408673) leebyron states that you can return both data and an error in your resolver (as per the spec) by returning an array e.g.

```
resolve() {
    return [ "value", new Error("2nd value is missing"), "value" ]
}
```

but this isn't working. I would've thought that the following should work (modified from [getting started](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/#writing-code)):

```
import { graphql, buildSchema } from 'graphql'

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`)

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint

var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return [ 'Hello world!', new Error('apocalypse') ]
  }
}

// Run the GraphQL query '{ hello }' and print out the response
graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

and should return

```
{ 
  data: { hello: 'Hello world!' },
  errors: [{ message: 'apocalypse' }]
}
```

So how should I be returning both data and errors in a resolver?
I'm currently testing this with graphql (js) version 0.13.2